# How to calculate averages of a 2D array, then initialize to a new array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, average

I have an existing 2 dimensional array of student grades, and I want to create a new array of GPAs of those grades. I know how to calculate the averages using nested `for` loops but I don't know how to take the resulting GPA, then have it automatically be initialized as an element in its own, new array.

This is what I'm using to calculate the GPAs:

```
double[][] grades = {
    { 3.83, 9.21, 9.25, 0.84, 1.40, 7.90, 1.41, 5.15 },
    { 5.09, 3.66, 3.04, 3.02, 8.59, 2.34, 8.86, 7.40 },
    { 5.35, 0.85, 8.56, 7.37, 2.78, 3.19, 2.04, 5.70 },
    { 9.25, 9.62, 7.08, 7.27, 9.86, 5.88, 9.86, 9.70 },
    { 3.39, 2.75, 1.23, 1.04, 3.87, 8.72, 4.60, 6.21 }
};

// CREATE NEW ARRAY OF GPAS
double[] gpa = new double[grades.length];
for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {//start of calculate gpa loop
    double sum = 0;
    double avg; 
    for (int j = 0; j < grades[i].length; j++){     
        sum += grades[i][j];   
    }
 avg = (sum/grades[i].length);
}
```

What I'm trying to get is an array like `double[] gpa = {4.87, 5.25, 4.48, 8.57, 3.98}`, can someone give a hint as to how to initialize these, maybe with another nested `for` loop? That's the only solution I've been able to come up with but I can't get the order of statements right, and it either comes back as an error or just initializes all of the elements to 0.00

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Just missing an assignment `gpa[i] = avg;` to set the GPA of the i-th student to the average you just calculated for them right after `avg = (sum/grades[i].length);`.

That said, with Java's [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) you can make this a "functional-ish" one-liner:

```java
var gpa = Arrays.stream(grades)
    .mapToDouble((x) -> Arrays.stream(x)
        .average()
        .getAsDouble()).toArray()
```

(broken across multiple lines for readability)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new integer variable above your outer for-loop, to hold an index.
Initialize it with `0`.

After your assignment of `avg`, place the value at `gpa[index++]`.

```java
double[] gpas = new double[grades.length];
double sum;
int index = 0;
for (double[] values : grades) {
    sum = 0;
    for (double gpa : values) sum += gpa;
    gpas[index++] = sum / values.length;
}
```

Output

```
[4.873749999999999, 5.249999999999999, 4.48, 8.565, 3.9762500000000003]
```

Comment: @user16320675, I try to avoid iterative for-loops if it's possible.  Not from a design standpoint, just for readability.

Comment: @user16320675, sure it is.  That's why they created the enhanced for-loop.  It's mentioned in _[The C Programming Language, by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)_.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to [Lunatic (`stackoverflow.com`)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7185318/luatic)'s [answer (`stackoverflow.com`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76345787/how-to-calculate-averages-of-a-2d-array-then-initialize-to-a-new-array/76345808#76345808), but avoids the "complex" inner lambda by further mapping:

```
List<Double> gpa = Arrays.stream(values)
    .map(Arrays::stream)
    .map(DoubleStream::average)
    .map(OptionalDouble::orElseThrow)
    .toList();
```

[<kbd>`ideone.com` demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/v29CyA)<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>
Notice that I had to use `.collect(Collectors.toList())` instead of [`.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) since `ideone.com` supports only Java 12 at the time of writing, and `Stream::toList` was introduced in Java 16</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a loop solution, then here is one way.

- first, declare a `gpas` array to hold the averages. As long as this is a primitive numeric array, it will be initialized with zeroes.
- then, you will need two loops.

  - the `outer loop` iterates over each `student` (the rows of `grades`).
  - the `inner loop` iterates over each `student grade` (the columns of `grades`).
- for each `student grade` add that to the `gpas` array for that student
- then compute the average as before.
- When printing out, you can use [System.printf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) to format to two decimal places.

```
double[] gpas = new double[grades.length];

for (int student = 0; student < grades.length; student++) {
    for (int studentGrade = 0; studentGrade < grades[student].length; studentGrade++) {
        gpas[student] += grades[student][studentGrade];
    }
    gpas[student] /= grades[student].length;
}
for(double gpa : gpas) {
    System.out.printf("%.2f ", gpa);
}
System.out.println();
```

prints